# MySQL selecting rows that are not in grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL table of sample data:

```
    create table prices (
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      store_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      item INTEGER NOT NULL,
      price FLOAT NOT NULL
    );

    insert into prices values(1,1,1,1.25);
    insert into prices values(2,1,2,.99);
    insert into prices values(3,2,2,1.20);
    insert into prices values(4,3,3,3.25);
    insert into prices values(5,3,1,1.35);
```

I am looking for a query to select any `store_id` that a company would not use to purchase product. For example in `prices`, `store_id` 2 would not be used because `item` 2 can be bought for cheaper from `store_id` 1.

How would I go about this? Thank you.

Comment: store_id = 2 could be used for another item, right? So do you want store_id returned in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this query:

```
select item, min(price) minprice
from prices
group by item
```

you get the minimum price for each item.
If you `left join` the table `prices` to the above query and keep only the non matching rows (meaning rows that don't have the cheapest price for that item), you will get all the stores and items that can be found cheaper:

```
select p.*
from prices p left join (
  select item, min(price) minprice
  from prices
  group by item
) g on g.item = p.item and g.minprice = p.price
where g.item is null
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aFSzrGJL6GwPQC5kgQvKDP/0).
Results:

```
| id  | store_id | item | price |
| --- | -------- | ---- | ----- |
| 3   | 2        | 2    | 1.2   |
| 5   | 3        | 1    | 1.35  |
```

If you want only the stores that you would not buy anything from:

```
select p.store_id
from prices p left join (
  select item, min(price) minprice
  from prices
  group by item
) g on g.item = p.item and g.minprice = p.price
group by p.store_id
having sum(g.item is not null) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aFSzrGJL6GwPQC5kgQvKDP/1).
Results:

```
| store_id |
| -------- |
| 2        |
```

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I wanted. I was able to get a table listing the cheapest price of each item and what store it was cheapest at (that was easy), but I was stuck on how to return the the stores wouldn't be used (all the items offered can be found cheaper at another store).

Comment: So that returns the items that aren't used, however store 3 is used to get item 3 (because it's the only store that has it). How would you just return `store_id` 2 because that's the only store we don't get anything from?

Comment: Forpas, I don't really understand exactly what the `having sum(g.item is not null) = 0` is doing. Could you provide a brief explanation?

Comment: See this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aFSzrGJL6GwPQC5kgQvKDP/2 It is the query without the group by p.store_id and the having clause. The rows with nulls are the rows where the item is not sold at its lowest price. If a store has only nulls then `sum(g.item is not null)` is `0` and this happens only for store=2. If a store has at least 1 not null then `sum(g.item is not null)` is `>0` and this means that this store has at least 1 item sold at its lowest price.

Comment: Thank you. That is a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, MIN(price) from prices group by item
```

Gives you the **store_id** which has the cheapest **item**.

Example output:

> id | store_id | item | price | MIN(price)
>
> 1  |    1     |   1  |  1.25 |   1.25
>
> 2  |    1     |   2  |  0.99 |   0.99
>
> 4  |    3     |   3  |  3.25 |   3.25